# MVC web app - where to ensure data validity?

Tags: spring, model-view-controller, spring-mvc, validation

I'm using Spring 3 but this question is more widely applicable, I think.

I have a web app with a front controller (a Spring `DispatcherServlet`).  From there a service is called which in turn uses a DAO or two to accomplish the desired task, such as causing a record to be inserted into the database.

Where do I ensure the data is valid?  Let's say I have an entry that has a maximum length of 50 characters - at what point should I assert the input's length is <= 50?

If I check validity in the controller then it's possible other code calling the services could be written that doesn't verify data.

I could check the validity in the service layer, but perhaps someone may write a service that doesn't check the validity of the data, thus passing "bad" data to a DAO.

It then may seem obvious to put the validity checks in the DAOs - would that then impact my ability to test the code?

What are the best practices when it comes to checking data validity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the services can be called from other than the controller, you could do the validation in the service layer. You could throw a custom exception from the service if the input data is invalid. The caller can get the information about what data caused the validation error by looking at the details of the Exception.

Comment: Thank you.  I agree with your logic.  Since I have services that use multiple DAOs I do some light validation in the service layers but as the DAO is the last "line of defense" before the data store I do the most stringent validation there.